# What is .toString doing in this parameter- vehicle.toString+"firstImage"

Tags: scala, tostring, scala-gatling

Just starting out with scala and gatling. I am trying to understand code written by another team member. 
The code is:

```scala
UploadFile.uploadFile(vehicle.toString+"firstImage", sessionHeaders, ImagePath,vehicle.toString);
```

`uploadFile` is a method in UploadFile.scala
and the `uploadFile` method is defined as:

```scala
def uploadFile(name:String, headers:Map[String,String], path:String, param:String)
```

so `vehicle.toString+"firstImage"` is the name and is a string. But I dont understand what is `vehicle.toString` -what is being done here? And then its concatenated to "firstImage". So then why not just write: ` "vehicle" + "firstImage"...?

Comment: I'm not a scala expert, but usually toString returns a human-readable representation of an object.

Comment: In other words, `vehicle` is probably not a string.  If it is, the `toString` call is redundant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is not necessarily true, it just returns a **String** representation on an object, if it is human-readable or not is due implementation - RenukaA I suppose vehicle is anything but a string, so in order to concatenate it to another string you first have to turn it into one _(scala has a strong and static type system, not a weak or dynamic one like JS and Python)_ - BTW, usually it would be better to do this using **String interpolation**: `s"${vehicle}firstImage"`

Comment: Like I said, I'm not a scala expert.  If this involves magnetic crystallography or nuclear physics, I'm not personally aware of it.  The upshot?  if `vehicle` is a object with a type other than string, toString has a purpose; if it's already a string, it probably does not.  Run a debugger over it and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

`vehicle` is probably not a `String` and therefore must be converted to a `String` before it is concatenated with `"firstImage"`.

If it is already a `String`, then the `.toString` is redundant